# Set UILabel text within code block

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlrequest

I have a code block for my NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest, and when I try to set a UILabel's text, the text is never set, even though the values are there. Here's my code:

```
    NSString *address = [addresses objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://myurl.com/%@", address]]];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
        {
            NSString *dataOfData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            if(![dataOfData isEqualToString:@"ERROR: address invalid"]) {
                [balanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balance: %@", dataOfData]];
                if(data) {
                    qrCodeButton.alpha = 1;
                }
            } else {
                errorLabel.text = @"This address is invalid.";
            }
        }
        else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
        {
            NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
            [balanceLabel setText:@"Server Error, Please Try Again"];
        }
        else if (error != nil){
            NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
        }
    }];
```

Why is the UILabel's text never set? Is there a limitation to code blocks? If so, how would I fix my problem? Cheers!

Comment: Try using NSLog to see if the code is running the way you expected

Comment: Yep. I made sure that the variables had the correct values.

Comment: No, I mean instead of trying to change the value of the label, put an NSLog there, to see if the code is executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because an NSOperationQueue is not the main thread. What you're doing is illegal. And the sad thing is that there is no need for it! Just say:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest 
     queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue]
     completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        // ... and the rest exactly as you have it now
```

All fixed. Your request is asynchronous on a background thread, but when it comes back to you on the completion handler, you'll be on the main thread and able to talk to the interface etc.

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: Curious - the docs say nothing about what it means to pass `nil` for the queue. Has it been determined that it means the "main" queue?

Comment: Interesting... it still didn't set the UILabel. I did NSLog the balance variable and I saw that it did have the correct value. What's up with that?

Comment: @rmaddy. Oooh. Okay, fixed that.

Comment: @matt Thanks so much! It turned out it was the [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] that was the necessary part. Who knew?

Answer (score 2):

Your code operates UI element should execute on main thread.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    if ([data length] > 0 && error == nil)
    {
        NSString *dataOfData = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        if(![dataOfData isEqualToString:@"ERROR: address invalid"]) {
            [balanceLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Balance: %@", dataOfData]];
            if(data) {
                qrCodeButton.alpha = 1;
            }
        } else {
            errorLabel.text = @"This address is invalid.";
        }
    }
    else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
        [balanceLabel setText:@"Server Error, Please Try Again"];
    }
    else if (error != nil){
        NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
    }
}) ;
```

Make sure `errorLabel` is not nil and the `UILabel` is visible (It is added in the view hierarchy and its frame is appropriate).

Comment: I'm curious... where do I put this? Inside of the code block, or outside? Because if it's outside the code block, the "data" variable is not set up.

Comment: Nope, nothing happened different than the last time. The UILabel was not set. I did verify via NSLogs that the values were appropriate.

Comment: @Burrito411 Are you sure the label is in the view hierarchy and it is visible? Check its superView, make sure `[label superview]` is not nil.

Comment: Absolutely. It says "Balance: " beforehand, and I checked the left menu and it says that the label is part of the general view.